# Error "Could not find main class" when trying to launch an exe file

Tags: java, jar, exe

I've done quite a bit of research on this problem but a lot of them have to do with running executable jar files.

My problem is I have an .exe file that loads .jar files from a folder. Originally the .exe file was working but after decompiling the .jar file to change a string value and exporting it back into a jar file the .exe file is no longer able to find the main class. I haven't changed the location or any of the names of the classes inside the .jar file so I'm unsure why this error is occurring.

I am not sure what to do as I'm not experienced in java. I have tried opening the .exe file in an editor but I don't see the option to do so.

Also as a side problem, commands like javac don't work in my command prompt and I'm also unaware of what to do about that.

I'd REALLY appreciate any help as I've been trying to solve this for a few hours now and it's starting to get on my nerves.

I am using JD-Gui to decompile the .jar file and Eclipse to edit the decompiled file and export it back into a .jar file.

Comment: can you describe step by step to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @elbraulio I figured out a better way to change the files but now I'm running into a new problem. I have saved the .jar file as a compressed folder and extracted the source file I need to change. I Decompilled it and changed the string variable and now I'm stuck at recompiling. When I go to recompile in my console I get a ton of string errors. So I used the option -encoding UTF-8 and now there's even more errors. I'm unsure of what to do as this wasn't happening before.